# Scroll by Blocks

Tags: jquery

I have 2 full screen sized `div` elements. I want them to be like slides, so if the user scrolls down a bit it scrolls to 2nd div, if the user scrolls up it scrolls up all the way to top.

However it is not working. I can't scroll up, yet it works on scroll down. 
I'm new to jQuery, detailed answers would be nice.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    $('html body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#scrollHere').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $('html body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}
.blue {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="box blue"></div>
<div class="box" id="scrollHere"></div>
```

Comment: I think, It's caused by animation speed

Comment: One obvious problem is the fact that jquery animations go into a queue, combined with the fact that the scroll event gets fired quite a bit while scrolling. That's likely the entire problem.

Comment: @kevinB Thank you for the comment, It seems that my "solution" is wrong. Can you provide good way to achieve this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more than the animation speed and well, let me say a 'rare' UI concept. Overriding default scroll behavior is like loosing the very basic control over my interaction with the page. Anyway.

**First**: If you watch the scroll and modify it, you have to cancel any further animations while you already animate. Therefore I added a boolean variable (isScrolling) to handle this.

**Second**: It's better to separate the scroll event listener (the detection of the scroll direction) from the interaction (I used a a timeout with a little delay). The result works but as I mentioned before, it feels strange.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var isScrolling = false;
var timer = null;

// method to initialize and handle the scroll override
function triggerScroll(direction) {
    // do not proceed in case we have an active timer
    if (timer) {return;}
    // get target position
    var topPos = (direction === 'down') ? $('#scrollHere').offset().top : 0;
    // run this with a little delay
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('html body').animate({
          scrollTop: topPos
        }, 1000, function() {
           // animation done - reset everything
           isScrolling = false;
           clearTimeout(timer);
           timer = false;
           lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        });
    },50);
}

// your event listener - detects direction 
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  // do not proceed if we already have a scroll event
  if(isScrolling) {return;}
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st >= lastScrollTop) {
    // delegate to sep. function
    triggerScroll('down');
  } else {
    triggerScroll('up');
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
  isScrolling = true;
});
```

If you ask for my opinion - it's more common to trigger these kind of animations by a click inside the page (an anchor navigation or whatever), if the user wants to use the scrollbar, let him scroll wherever he wants (or maybe interact after scroll is finished).

Comment: Thanks for the code. I think I'll use anchor as you adviced, you're right it feels really strange. I didn't thought it would be so strange and awkward :)